# Update and Edit on Resource Controller: Can't Find Query Results for Model

Tags: laravel-8, model-binding, laravel-resource, route-model-binding

I have a resource controller in my Laravel app, where all resource functions are placed. So far I have the creation and store functions working fine, but it falls on edit() and update(). As far as I can see, the issue is that it's not grabbing the model instance. I'm trying to pinpoint where I've gone wrong.
Below is my routes web.php code.

```
// Website Development
Route::resource('website-development-orders',DevelopmentOrderController::class);
```

and here is my controller code

```
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\DevelopmentOrder  $developmentOrder
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(DevelopmentOrder $developmentOrder)
    {
        //
        dd($developmentOrder);
        $this->authorize('update', $developmentOrder);
        $categories = Development::all();
        $payment_methods = PaymentMethod::all();
        return view('development-orders.edit', compact('categories', 'payment_methods', 'developmentOrder'));
    }
```

and finally, my blade file from I am accessing DevelopmentOrderController,

```
<td>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <a href="{{ route('website-development-orders.edit',$commission->id) }}"
            class="d-inline-flex btn btn-sm btn-warning mr-2">Edit</a>
        <form class="d-inline-flex"
            action="{{ route('website-development-orders.destroy', $commission->id) }}"
            method="POST"
            onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to delete this Package?');">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="Delete">
        </form>
        @if ($commission->status == 0)
        <a href="{{ route('refund-development.refund', $commission->id) }}"
            class="d-inline-flex btn btn-sm btn-info ml-2 mr-2">Refund</a>
        @endif
    </div>
</td>
```

After that I replaced **developmentOrder** with **website_development_order** it works fine so please suggest how can use **developmentOrder** to fetch the model data.

Answer (score 1):

Change your route from

```
Route::resource('website-development-orders',DevelopmentOrderController::class);
```

to

```
Route::resource('website-development-orders', DevelopmentOrderController::class, ['parameters' => ['website_development_order' => 'developmentOrder']);
```

This will change your default route parameter *website_development_order* to *developmentOrder*